# Drawing NSString in CGRect

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uiimage, cgrect

I'm trying to draw a NSString at the bottom of my CGRect. So far I've been able to have the text to be at the top centered but I need it to be positioned at the bottom. I also tried DrawAtPoint but that didn't work. Here's my code that I currently have: 

*UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);*

```
CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
[img drawInRect:aRectangle];

[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
NSInteger fontSize = 25;
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: fontSize];

[text drawInRect:aRectangle withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];



UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method:
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode
get the text size, then calculate the left top point and use drawAtPoint to draw the text

Comment: I tried using drawAtPoint a view times but for some reason it isn't adding the drawing on top of the rect.

Comment: you also can you drawInRect, but the rect size is calculated by sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode

Comment: Here's my entire code so you can have a better understanding about what I'm doing.

Comment: Never mind, I can't post that much characters in a comment; I'm essentially calling a function and it's returning this Rect but for some reason NSString.drawAtPoint isn't adding to the Rect.

Comment: drawAtPoint just draw single line, no wrapping.

Comment: How would I place that onto the image though?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
 -(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text
{
  CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 1000); //set width for string to wrap.
  UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
  CGSize strSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
  if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(strSize,NO,0.0);
  else
    // iOS is < 4.0 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(strSize);

  CGRect newframe = CGRectMake(0, 0, strSize.width, strSize.height);
  [text  drawInRect:newframe 
                  withFont:font 
             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
                 alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft]; 
  UIImage *testImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
  return testImg;
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code but the image that was returned was just black. I tried adding in [[UIColor whiteColor] set]; to set the text color as white but that didn't work.

Comment: My mistake, the image is just being returned extremely small; Is it possible for me to just add that string on the bottom of a UIImage? That's essentially all I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this code helped my problem extremely.

```
- (UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height;
    //lon = h - lon;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

    char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// "05/05/09";
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);


    //rotate text
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0, 5, text, strlen(text));


    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```